# How can you get foreign key values from a DBEntityEntry?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an audit log of any changes at point of save using Entity Framework.  So far I have it working fairly well, storing all changes made to each field using the code below:

```
foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
{
    // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
    if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
    {
        result.Add(new AuditLog()
        {
            UserID = UserId,
            EventDateUTC = changeTime,
            EventType = "M",    // Modified
            TableName = tableName,
            RecordID = primaryKey.ToString(),
            ColumnName = propertyName,
            OriginalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString(),
            NewValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is how to get values for any foreign keys that belong to this object. For example: I have a vehicle object that has relationships to a series of lookup tables, such as gearbox, model etc. If these values change the audit table will store the changed id, but I want to store the actual value.

Is there a way of getting the foreign key value in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty... this is an old question but I've spent the last while working this out because I had the exact same requirements. Maybe there is an easier way, but here's the code I used:

Your original code, slightly modified for my purposes (RecordID is always an int), and calling the new method to calculate the new value

```
foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
                if (!Equals(dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
                {
                    var newVal = getNewValueAsString(dbEntry, tableName, propertyName);

                    result.Add(new AuditLog
                                {
                                    UserID = currentUser.ID,
                                    Timestamp = changeTime,
                                    EventType = EventType.Modified,
                                    TableName = tableName,
                                    RecordID = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<int>(keyName),
                                    ColumnName = propertyName,
                                    OriginalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null : dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString(),
                                    NewValue = newVal
                                }
                        );
                }
            }
```

A new attribute called "IsName"

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class IsNameAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

Marking the "name" property of foreign key models with the IsName attribute (note the code will default to a property called "Name" if it doesn't find one)

```
[Required]
[IsName]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

And the heavy lifting code

```
 private string getNewValueAsString(DbEntityEntry dbEntry, string tableName, string propertyName)
    {
        var fkVal = getForeignKeyValue(tableName, propertyName, dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName));
        return fkVal != null ? fkVal.ToString()
                            : (dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) == null ? null
                                : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString());
    }

    private object getForeignKeyValue(string tableName, string propertyName, object foreignKeyID)
    {
        // if this property is part of a foreign key, we need to instead look that up and store the value of the
        // foreign key

        // first get all the foreign keys in the system
        var workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        var items = workspace.GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
        if (items == null) return null;
        var fk = items.Where(a => a.IsForeignKey).ToList();
        // now we look into the FK attributes and find that the "To Role" is out current table, and the
        // "To Property" is out current property. The underscore is a bit of an assumption that the foreign
        // key name built by EF will be ENTITY_BLAH_BLAH
        var thisFk = fk.Where(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToRole.Name.StartsWith(tableName + "_"))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToProperties[0].Name == propertyName);
        // if fkname has no results, this is not a foreign key and we are done
        if (thisFk == null) return null;

        // Now that we know the foriegn key, we need to lookup the Name value in the other table

        // find the assembly
        var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        // build the type for the foreign key entity
        // e.g. if the current entity is Task, and the property is StatusID, we are 
        // getting the "TaskStatus" type with reflection
        // "User" class is an object in the Models namespace - you could just hardcode the string if you want
        var foreignKeyType = assembly.GetType(typeof(User).Namespace + "." +
                  thisFk.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromRole.GetEntityType().Name);

        // get the DbSet, same as: "(new DBContext()).EntityName"
        var fkSet = Set(foreignKeyType);
        // and find the row in that table
        var fkItem = fkSet.Find(foreignKeyID);

        // find the first column marked with the "IsName" attribute, otherwise default to "Name"
        var nameColProperty = foreignKeyType.GetProperties()
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IsNameAttribute), false).Any());
        string nameCol = "Name";
        if (nameColProperty != null) nameCol = nameColProperty.Name;
        var nameColProperty2 = fkItem.GetType().GetProperty(nameCol);
        if (nameColProperty2 == null) return null;

        // get the value
        var fkValue = nameColProperty2.GetValue(fkItem, null);

        // and now, my brain hurts
        return fkValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on [@JamesR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26877018/4660897).

My goal was to make the code more generic so it could be used for multiple foreign keys connecting to different tables.

Improvements worth noting:

- I moved the code that gets the list of foreign keys outside of the propertyName `foreach` loop. Since the list of FKs doesn't change based on the specific property, there is no reason to retrieve a new list every time. If there are many FKs in the system, this can take a while, so you don't want to repeat the process unnecessarily.
- Instead of hard-coding a specific class type like `GetType(typeof(User)`, I retrieved the foreign key table name from the FK using:

  ```
  string lookUpTableName = thisFk.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromRole.Name;
  ```

  Then, although the referenced FK property name will usually be `ID`, since it can vary, I retrieved the FK property name as well:

  ```
  string lookUpPropertyName = thisFk.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromProperties[0].Name;
  ```

  I then used [`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208(v=vs.110).aspx) to dynamically plug in the table and column name and retrieve the foreign key text value.
- If a property is a FK, I get the FK text value for both the original a new value.

---

**Complete code:**

First, get a list of all the foreign keys in the system.

```
IObjectContextAdapter contextAdapter = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this);
MetadataWorkspace workspace = contextAdapter.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
var items = workspace.GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace);

List<AssociationType> FKList = items == null ? null
    : items.Where(a => a.IsForeignKey).ToList();
```

Then, loop through the list of properties and replace the original and current values with the foreign key values when a FK exists.

```
foreach (string propertyName in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
{
    var original = entry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
    var current = entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);

    if (FKList != null)
    {
        GetPossibleForeignKeyValues(tableName, propertyName, ref original, ref current,
            FKList, contextAdapter);
    }

    if ((original == null && current != null) ||
        (original != null && !original.Equals(current)))
    {
        result.Add(new AuditLog()
        {
            UserID = UserId,
            EventDateUTC = changeTime,
            EventType = "M",    // Modified
            TableName = tableName,
            RecordID = primaryKey.ToString(),
            ColumnName = propertyName,
            OriginalValue = original != null ? original.ToString() : "NULL",
            NewValue = current != null ? current.ToString() : "NULL"
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the actually foreign key finding code:

```
private void GetPossibleForeignKeyValues(string tableName, string propertyName,
    ref object originalFKValue, ref object newFKValue,
    List<AssociationType> FKList, IObjectContextAdapter contextAdapter)
{
    // If this property is part of a foreign key, look up and set the FKValue to the text
    // value of the foreign key. Otherwise, just leave the FKValue alone.

    // Look into the FK attributes and find that the "To Role" is out current table,
    // and the "To Property" is out current property.
    AssociationType thisFk = FKList.FirstOrDefault(x =>
        tableName.Contains(x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToRole.Name)
        && propertyName.Contains(x.ReferentialConstraints[0].ToProperties[0].Name));

    // If fkname has no results, this is not a foreign key and we are done.
    if (thisFk != null)
    {
        // Now that we know the foriegn key, look up the Name value in the other table.
        string lookUpTableName = thisFk.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromRole.Name;
        string lookUpPropertyName = thisFk.ReferentialConstraints[0].FromProperties[0].Name;

        //Assuming the FK column name is "Name".
        //Use the idea in @JamesR's solution or some sort of LookUp table if it is not.
        string commandText = BuildCommandText("Name", lookUpTableName, lookUpPropertyName);

        originalFKValue = contextAdapter.ObjectContext
            .ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(commandText, new SqlParameter("FKID", originalFKValue))
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? originalFKValue;

        newFKValue = contextAdapter.ObjectContext
            .ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(commandText, new SqlParameter("FKID", newFKValue))
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? originalFKValue;

    }
}
```

This is the method I used to build the SQL CommandText:

```
private string BuildCommandText(string columnName, string lookUpTableName, 
    string lookUpPropertyName)    
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append("SELECT ");
    builder.Append(columnName);
    builder.Append(" FROM ");
    builder.Append(lookUpTableName);
    builder.Append(" WHERE ");
    builder.Append(lookUpPropertyName);
    builder.Append(" = @FKID");

    //The result query will look something like:
    //SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE PropertyName = @FKID

    return builder.ToString();
}
```